# Android Studio - Condition is always true?

Tags: android, if-statement

This would be the first time I post a question since I couldn't find the answer to this. Something really weird is happening with my if/else statements. My code was working perfectly for the past week, but recently it kept on telling me that a statement is always true?

My code is the following:

```
    int checking = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (checking != 1) {
        speaker.setChecked(true);
    } else if (checking == 1) {
        speaker.setChecked(false);
    }

}
```

This says `checking == 1` is always true which makes sense, but if I switch it around to:

```
if (checking == 1) {
    speaker.setChecked(true);
} else if (checking != 1) {
    speaker.setChecked(false);
}
```

This says that `checking != 1` is always true as well. Can someone help?

Comment: In both cases, the second `if` is pointless, because it wouldn't be going to the first `if`'s `else` branch otherwise. It's suggesting that you just remove those.

Comment: Just chiming in with the fact that Android Studio sometimes gets this wrong. I got the warning `Condition 'base == 10' is always 'true'` recently. The thing is, that `base` is a protected variable, not private, and although it's always 10 *in my class*, it gets changed changed in a subclass. If I were to blindly listen to Android Studio and unwrap the **if** statement, I would break things down the line. This is a dangerous warning for AS to be getting wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing this warning is:

You have set `int checking = 1` and you are either checking:

1. `if (checking != 1)` which is always `true`
2. Or `checking == 1` which is also always `true`

Due to this other `else if` condition will not be executed at all.

The warning will be only removed if you try to change value of `checking` either at runtime or using some conditions at compile time.

If your intention is just to set the `speaker.setChecked()` you can do following:

`speaker.setChecked(checking == 1)`

**Note:** This will not remove the warning

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it will.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a logic of editor. In first if statement, you check `checking == 1` and the second if statement, you negative the statement. The editor will understand the second if statement alway true

I think you should replace `else if` to `else`. Sorry my bad English.

Comment: Hi hientp, and thank you for helping. I did do the 'else' by itself but it kept on skipping the first if statement so that's why I added the 'else if' to check why it was skipping it and it kept on telling me that it was always true?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int checking = 1;
boolean isChecked = false; 

isChecked = ((checking == 1) ? true : false)
speaker.setChecked(isChecked)
```

Comment: Or simply `speaker.setChecked(checking != 1)`. However, this isn't a really an answer to OP's question as to what the error message means.